# How to make abbreviations/acronyms in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

*new to coding* I'm trying to make a function that makes "abbreviations/acronyms" of words, e.g. 'I love you' -> 'ily'.
I've tried rewriting the code in many ways but console.log only shows me the first letter of the first given word.

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  let abbrev = words[0];
  let after = 0;
  let i = 0;
  for (const letter of words) {
    if (letter === '') {
      i = words.indexOf('', after);
      abbrev += words[i + 1];
    }
    after++;
  }
  return abbrev;
}
const words = 'a bc def';
let result = makeAbbr(words);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `"I love you".match(/\b(\S)/g).join("")`

Comment: @GottZ Is there any simple way? Like changing something in my code? I'm not familiar with the "match"  and "join" yet.

Comment: `letter === ''` ---> `letter === ' '` and `words.indexOf('', after)` ---> `words.indexOf(' ', after)` - Note the space between single quotes.

Comment: basically `/\b(\S)/g/` is a regular expression that checks for word boundaries with `\b` so something like the start and the end of a word. `\S` checks for a non-whitespace character (excluding linebreaks). the `(\S)` ensures you want to match what ever character is matched there. `/g` will match more than once. `.join` is simply a function that joins iterable objects like arrays and match results together, using what ever is specified as delimiter.

Comment: OMG, so the space was the problem. Gosh... Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: `words.indexOf(' ', after)` could also change to `words.indexOf(letter, after)`, though this doesn't matter that much. It just reduces the amount of hardcoded values.

Comment: I primarily threw this match here in comments so you see there are alternatives available to your problem. I strongly recommend learning RegExp, since they are a insanely powerful tool. (also keep in mind, the given match would also work with: `"    I   love   you   "`)

Comment: Alternative solution: `function makeAbbr(words) {
  let abbrev = "";
  words.split(" ").forEach(word => abbrev += word[0]);
  return abbrev;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is my implementation of your function:
Split the sentence into an array, get the first letter of each word and join them into one string.

```js
const makeAbbr = string => string.split(' ').map(word => word[0]).join('');

console.log(makeAbbr('stack overflow'));
console.log(makeAbbr('i love you'));
```

`

Comment: it is just an example to demonstrate the function

Comment: You might want to consider linking to (beginner friendly) resources that cover what `split`, `map` and `join` are. Perhaps other SO questions would be ideal for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Without using arrays. But you really should learn about them.

1. Start by trimming leading and trailing whitespace.
2. Add the first character to your acronym.
3. Loop over the rest of the string and add the current character to the acronym if the previous character was a space (and the current character isn't).

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  words = words.trim();
  const length = words.length;
  let acronym = words[0];

  for(let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    if(words[i - 1] === ' ' && words[i] !== ' ') {
       acronym += words[i];
    }
  }

  return acronym;
}
console.log(makeAbbr('I love you'));
console.log(makeAbbr('I     love     you'));
console.log(makeAbbr('   I    love    you   '));
```

---

And here's the version for GottZ

```js
function w(char) {
   char = char.toLocaleLowerCase();
   const coll = Intl.Collator('en');
   const cmpA = coll.compare(char, 'a');
   const cmpZ = coll.compare(char, 'z');

   return cmpA >= 0 && cmpZ <= 0;
}

function makeAbbr(words) {
  words = words.trim();
  const length = words.length;
  if(!length) return '';

  let acronym = words[0];

  for(let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    if(!w(words[i - 1]) && w(words[i])) {
       acronym += words[i];
    }
  }

  return acronym;
}
console.log(makeAbbr('I love you'));
console.log(makeAbbr('I     love     you'));
console.log(makeAbbr('   I    love    you   '));
console.log(makeAbbr('   \tI ...  ! love \n\r   .you   '));
console.log(makeAbbr('   \tI ...  ! Löve \n\r   .ÿou   '));
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there is multiple spaces in a row

Comment: meh. fixing it is easy enough :)

Comment: ha. now try `"   I    love    you   "` :D there is just a big reason why I prefer using regexp for such things.

Comment: @GottZ `commit -m "fix leading spaces"`

Comment:  there you go. finally someone appreciating the command line. now.. .. what about tabs or other whitespace characters?

Comment: oh and you just deserved an upvote for that.

Comment: btw. other languages like rust would throw a out of bound exception when supplying an empty string. luckily, javascript just returns `undefined` in that case. there are so many ways to take care of people abusing this interface.. typeof and checking minimum length for example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted something using your approach, try this (code is commented)

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  let abbrev = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) { // Loop through every character except the last one
    if (i == 0 && words[i] != " ") { // Add the first character
      abbrev += words[i];
    } else if (words[i] == " " && words[i + 1] != " ") { // If current character is space and next character isn't
      abbrev += words[i + 1];
    }
  }
  return abbrev.toLowerCase();
}
const words = 'a bc def';
let result = makeAbbr(words);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your approach exactly, you had a typo on the line specified. A character can never be `""` (an empty string), but a character can be a space `" "`. Fixing this typo makes your solution work.

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  let abbrev = words[0];
  let after = 0;
  let i = 0;
  for (const letter of words) {
    if (letter === ' ') { // This line here
      i = words.indexOf(' ', after);
      abbrev += words[i + 1];
    }
    after++;
  }
  return abbrev.toLowerCase(); // Also added .toLowerCase()
}
const words = 'a bc def';
let result = makeAbbr(words);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things tripping you up.

1. `let abbrev = words[0];` is just taking the first letter of the word string you passed into the function, and at some point adding something new to it.
2. `for (const letter of words) {...}`: `for/of` statements are used for iterating over *arrays*, not strings.

Here's a remixed version of your code. It still uses `for/of` but this time we're creating an array of words from the string and iterating over that instead.

```js
function makeAbbr(str) {

  // Initialise `abbrev`
  let abbrev = '';

  // `split` the string into an array of words
  // using a space as the delimiter
  const words = str.split(' ');

  // Now we can use `for/of` to iterate
  // over the array of words
  for (const word of words) {

    // Now concatenate the lowercase first
    // letter of each word to `abbrev`
    abbrev += word[0].toLowerCase();
  }

  return abbrev;

}

console.log(makeAbbr('I love you'));
console.log(makeAbbr('One Two Three Four Five'));
```